# Error in adding preview actions to an aggregation in an Open Graph application

Tags: facebook, action

I am following the tutorial creating my first [Open Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Open_Graph_protocol) application. Everything works up until when I tried to add "Preview Actions" in an aggregation and created sample data for the authentication dialog. When I tried to save the data that I entered, I got the error (see also below)

> Something went wrong. We're working on getting it fixed as soon as we can.

How do I fix this issue?

---

```
Start time: 2011-10-07 10:34:02
End time : 2011-10-07 10:34:02
Place : 147330072002695
Tags: 833427
Image: an URL of an image
Reference : an URL of an image
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/tutorial/#define

Comment: I got an error, too, though it says: 0 is not a valid profile id.

Answer (score 2):

So I was getting the same error and then tried a few things different.

First, I created a Preview Object before creating a Preview Action. I added the image and title to the object and that created just fine.

Then, try creating a Preview Action - however; when you click on the 'Recipe' parameter - a list of created preview objects should appear. Select the one you just created. Leave all other parameters blank and that should successfully create a Preview Action.

The above worked for me to create a auth dialog with the aggregation preview.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's applicable for this. But in an opengraph object I had to use an absolute url to an image, including protocol, otherwise I got a similar exception.